# In loops i can not summarize the results in a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I'm sorry, maybe the solution in my problem is easy, but I am still new to R, and any help
here is appreciated!

I want to create a data frame, or a matrix in which the output of each loop will be stored.
Here is the program:

```
n<-c(10,8,7,5)
n_goal<-c(8,9,9,4)
w<-c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)
matrix<-mat.or.vec(6,4)
FI<-function(n_t) {
  (((n_goal[1]-n[1]+W[1]-f[1]+n_t[1])^2)+((n_goal[2]-n[2]+W[2]-f[2]+n_t[2]-n_t[1])^2)+
  ((n_goal[3]-n[3]+W[3]-f[3]+n_t[3]-n_t[2])^2)+((n_goal[4]-n[4]+W[4]-f[4]-n_t[3])^2))
}
for (i in 1:6) {
    W<-c(n*w)
    sf<-c(1,1,1,1)
    f1<-W%*%sf
    f<-c(f1,0,0,0)
    out<-nlm(FI, n_t<-c(0,0,0), hessian=TRUE)
    for (i in 1:3) {
        if(out$estimate[i]<0)
            out$estimate[i]=0
    }
    n<-c(n-W+f-c(out$estimate,0)+c(0,out$estimate))
    matrix[i, ]<-n
    print(n)
}
matrix
```

`n` is the output I want to store in the matrix in each loop to have subsequently a plot.

(Each `n` will be a point and I'd like to have 6 separately points---six 4 dimensions vectors)

The problem is here: I get wrong matrix:

```
> print(matrix)
         [,1] [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 0.000000    0 0.000000 0.000000
[2,] 0.000000    0 0.000000 0.000000
[3,] 8.000002    9 8.999999 3.999998
[4,] 0.000000    0 0.000000 0.000000
[5,] 0.000000    0 0.000000 0.000000
[6,] 0.000000    0 0.000000 0.000000
```

only third row has right numbers, all the other have zero, while print(n) seems right

```
[1] 8.0 9.0 8.5 4.5
[1] 8.00 9.00 8.95 4.05
[1] 8.000003 9.000000 8.999999 3.999998
[1] 8.000002 9.000000 8.999999 3.999998
[1] 8.000002 9.000000 8.999999 3.999998
[1] 8.000002 9.000000 8.999999 3.999998
```

Actually I want latest matrix to be the same with print(n).

Also, I tried to create a data frame but it is difficult for me because outputs are
vectors and not single numbers.

Answer (score 0):

without getting to deep into what your function is trying to do...

If `print(n)` is indeed giving the right answer (i.e. each loop is correct), then you probably want the `out <- rbind(out, n)` command:

so the *pseudocode* might be

```
#start of code
out <- vector()
# rest of variables
FI <- blah blaha..{
#etc 
for (i in 1:6)
{
#etc..rst of loop
# not print (n)
out<- rbind(out,n)
}

return(out)
}
```

or similar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: OK please close the Q if that is what you want.

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your optimzations. Since `nlm` is for linear optimizations I tried first to simplify your minimized function to use R vectorized features. I also avoid using global variables to avoid side effect.

```
FIV <- function(n_t,n_goal,f,W) {
  n_th <- c(n_t,0)
  n_tt <- c(0,n_t)
  sum((n_goal-n+W-f+n_th-n_tt)^2)
}
```

For clarity and better performance, Then I isolate static initialization statements from the main loop.

```
## initilizations  
n <- c(10,8,7,5)
n_goal <- c(8,9,9,4)
w <- c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)
matrix <-mat.or.vec(6,4)
sf <- c(1,1,1,1)
```

For looping , no need to use a `for` here. Use `replicate` since you are repeating the same task without using the index and because you want to store the final result in a matrix.

```
replicate(6,{
  W  <- c(n*w) 
  f1 <- W%*%sf
  f  <- c(f1,0,0,0)
  out<- nlm(FIV, c(0,0,0), n_goal,f,W,hessian=TRUE)
  est <- out$estimate
  est[est<0] <- 0
  c(n-W+f-c(est,0)+c(0,est))
})

# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0
# [2,]  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0
# [3,]  8.5  8.5  8.5  8.5  8.5  8.5
# [4,]  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5
```

**EDIT** You can use `sapply` also and update `n` at each iteration ( note the use of global assignment `<<-` since it is a global variable)

```
sapply(1:6,function(x){
  W  <- c(n*w) 
  f1 <- W%*%sf
  f  <- c(f1,0,0,0)
  out<- nlm(FIV, c(0,0,0), n_goal,f,W,hessian=TRUE)
  est <- out$estimate
  est[est<0] <- 0
  n <<- c(n-W+f-c(est,0)+c(0,est))
  n
})
```

Comment: Well changes are really usefull, thank you! the problem is that n changes at each iteration. Thats why you found a matrix with the samebolumns. Can i use this code with for?

Comment: @user3035550 yes of course. But how do you change n? better to replace `replicate` by `sapply` in this case. Something like: `sapply(1:6,function(x){ n <- something; the_rest_of_replicate_code})`

Comment: In each loop i have n<-c(n-W+f-c(out$estimate,0)+c(0,out$estimate)) where initial n is n <- c(10,8,7,5). Next n will be (8.0 9.0 8.5 4.5) and i must use this to find the next one n.. That's my problem!

Comment: agstudy sorry, but could you be more concrete about your latest idea? it seems interesting and i would like to trial it.